# InsertAndGetIdAsync take long time to insert into DB when DB have any large data table - ABP Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, frameworks, sql-insert, abp

[image]

My DB have some table and PO*_*Products table
I'm using `InsertAndGetIdAsync` to insert into PO_Products table but it takes so long when my DB has a table including large data (= 100000 record), not PO_Products.
When truncating all tables including large data, inserting is so fast.
PO_Product has no relationship to other tables.
I don't know why?

Does anyone knows why and can you explain it to me? Thank so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InsertMany` for this process. When you autosave=true, the id assignment of the products in your list will be made.